# How to do Recursice Funciton Return List<>?

Tags: c#, recursion, youtube-api, uwp

i am trying get playlist on youtube and using Json Http Request.
youtube playlist api supports max 50 results so i want make a recursive funciton and that funciton should  return List.

```
    private async Task<List<Classes.PlayList>> GetPlayList(string id, string pageToken = null)
    {
        string JsonText = await x.GetJson(id, pageToken);
        List<Classes.PlayList> List = new List<Classes.PlayList>();
        if (JsonText == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            JObject JsonObj = JObject.Parse(JsonText);
            foreach (var item in JsonObj["items"])
            {
                List.Add(new Classes.PlayList
                {
                    image = (string)item["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["default"]["url"],
                    title = (string)item["snippet"]["title"],
                    videoId = (string)item["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"]

                });
            }
            if ((string)JsonObj["nextPageToken"] != null)
            {
                pageToken = (string)JsonObj["nextPageToken"];
                List = await GetPlayList(id, pageToken);
                return List;
            }
            else
            { return List; }

        }
```

Comment: OK i fixed //List.AddRange( await GetPlayList(id, pageToken));

Comment: You might want to write that as an answer and accept it.